# Merge multiple columns in a single object C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
public class Sample 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string GroupA { get; set; }

    public string GroupB { get; set; }

    public string GroupC { get; set; }
}
```

I receive a list like this:

```
5 | Test | A
5 | Test | B
```

How can I group by to return a result like this:

```
5 | Test | A | B

 var consolidatedChildren = list.GroupBy(c => new
                                    {
                                        c.Id,
                                        c.GroupA
                                    })
                                    .Select(gcs => new
                                    {
                                        Id = gcs.Key.Id,
                                        Children = gcs.ToList()
                                    });
```

How can I get the result.

Basically in C#, the final output will be:

```
 new { Id: 5, GroupA: "Test", GroupB: "A", GroupC: "B" }
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use this ``children = string.Join("|", gcs.Select(x=> x.GroupB));``

Comment: like need a list of objects in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) to get a `Children` value

```cs
var samples = new List<Sample>
{
    new Sample { Id = 5, GroupA = "Test", GroupB = "A" },
    new Sample { Id = 5, GroupA = "Test", GroupB = "B" }
};

var result = samples.GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.GroupA }, s => s.GroupB,
    (g, groups) => new { g.Id, g.GroupA, Children = string.Join("|", groups) });
```

To have a name for every child element within a group you can use `ToDictionary` method (declaring dynamic properties names for anonymous types isn't possible)

```cs
var result = samples
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.GroupA }, s => s.GroupB)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Id,
        g.Key.GroupA,
        Children = g.Select((name, index) => (name, index))
            .ToDictionary(tuple => $"Group{(char)(tuple.index + 66)}", tuple => tuple.name)
    });
```

Comment: thanks Pavel. I have updated the question. sorry, need a list of objects not formatted

Comment: @Gauravsa properties in anonymous type must be known at compile time, you should declare `GroupB`, `GroupC` by yourself, or switch to different output, like dictionary

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise with the wanted result;

```
var samples = new List<Sample>
{
    new Sample { Id = 5, GroupA = "Test", GroupB = "A" },
    new Sample { Id = 5, GroupA = "Test", GroupB = "B" }
};    

var result = samples.GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.GroupA }, s => s.GroupB,
                            (g, groups) => string.Join(" | ", g.Id, g.GroupA, string.Join(" | ", groups)))
                    .Select(c => c).FirstOrDefault();
```

The result is;

> 5 | Test | A | B

Comment: Like need a list of objects in c#

Answer (score 1):

I suggest several options

```
var list = new List<Sample>()
{
new Sample { Id = 5, GroupA = "Test", GroupB = "A", GroupC = "C" },
new Sample { Id = 5, GroupA = "Test", GroupB = "B", GroupC = "C" }
};

var consolidatedChildren = list.GroupBy(c => new
{
    c.Id,
    c.GroupA
})
.Select(gcs => new
{
    Id = gcs.Key.Id,
    Children = new
    {
        gcs.Key.Id,
        gcs.Key.GroupA,
        GroupB = gcs.Select(x => x.GroupB).ToList(),
        GroupC = gcs.Select(x => x.GroupC).ToList(),
    }
});
```

Or

```
var consolidatedChildren = list.GroupBy(c => new
{
    c.Id,
    c.GroupA
})
.Select(gcs => new
{
    gcs.Key.Id,
    gcs.Key.GroupA,
    GroupB = gcs.Select(x => x.GroupB).ToList(),
    GroupC = gcs.Select(x => x.GroupC).ToList(),
});
```

Or

```
var consolidatedChildren = list.GroupBy(c => new
{
    c.Id,
    c.GroupA
})
.Select(gcs => new
{
    gcs.Key.Id,
    gcs.Key.GroupA,
    GroupB = gcs.Select(x => x.GroupB).Distinct().ToList(),
    GroupC = gcs.Select(x => x.GroupC).Distinct().ToList(),
})
.ToList();
```